# Coarser topology on the reals that is Hausdorff and connected.

Tags: general-topology

I need to find a topology over $\mathbb{R}$ that is (strictly) coarser than its usual topology, and must be Hausdorff and connected. However, every topology that I had considered fails in one of those conditions. For instance, neither the cofinite topology and the topology generated by semi-rays are Hausdorff but both *are* connected topologies.

I don't know if such topology exists, can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean "coarser than the usual topology" or coarsest (of all possible topologies with those properties?)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I mean "coarser", sorry for my typo.

Comment: If the topology $\tau$ is coarser then the usual one, it's automatically connected: a disconnection in $\tau$ is also one in the usual topology.. All you need is Hausdorff.

Comment: Consider basic open sets of the form $(a,b)$ minus a countable dense subset of $(a,b)$. It's Hausdorff and connected, but locally, totally disconnected if I recall correctly.  (It's been 45 years since I looked at the example.)

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Nice example, but it's not coarser than the usual topology (your topology is not comparable to the usual topology).

Comment: @AlexKruckman You are right. I have been away from topology for several decades.

Comment: So the example in the accepted answer of the duplicate is fine and very simple.